# how to update data from database using php safely

Tags: php

i'm currently creating a website for fun, and im a total beginner on php, javascript, and mysql.

i have to update data from database. this is the structure of my database:

recordId(autonumber)
recordvalue(varchar)

and in my html i have a table that contains the recordID and the recordValue

when i click the edit button.

the recordValue is passed to a text input
and the recordId is passed to a hidden input.

is it safe?

or is there a better way of doing this safely.

i have read some basic articles about sql injection and session.

is it possible to change the hidden input value. on runtime. i mean after clicking the EDIT button. and that data will be send to my php code?

i have this php code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL sp_updatedata (?,?)");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 10); 
$stmt->bindParam(2, $u_name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: You're already using prepared statements. If you do this consistently, you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's crucial to understand the following: assume the user can see *everything* you send to the browser.  Using hidden form fields is **no** way to keep secrets safe. Just don't send it to the browser if you don't want the user to know it

Ok, on to your question: What happens in the browser (eg: moving record value to text box and record id to hidden field) has nothing to do with SQL Injection. SQL injection occurs when an attacker makes your DB execute unwanted queries. This happens because the programmer chose to insert values that came from the user directly into the query.  You see that a lot here on Stack, especially on registration and login queries:

```
SELECT * from users_table WHERE username = $_POST[username]
```

To protect yourself against SQL injection, use prepared statements

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT...WHERE username = ?");
...bind the parameters to $_POST[username], then execute
$stmt->execute()
```

**to recap**

1. Don't send anything to the browser/javascript that you don't want the user to see
2. Don't trust data that comes from the browser as legitimate or safe, and never include it directly in your queries

Comment: but how can i update the data or delete it? when i need the ID to execute the query? how can i hide the ID to the user. even if he view the source code? viewing the source code is easy right? but the user can't view the php code only the html code. i mean if i list the data into a html table. what im going to do is list the data with the ID. in order for the query which record to delete or update

Comment: I think that showing item ids to your users is fine, so what you plan to do is ok. I just wanted to make sure you understood that you cannot keep something secret if you're sending it to the browser.  You're right that PHP code can't be seen.